# what is the significance of using this.fileList = []; in the wire call?

Tags: lightning-web-components

If I remove this line `this.fileList = [];`, in wire call `<template if:true={fileList.length}>` is not working , why so?

```html
<template>
    <div class="c-container slds-box slds-p-around_none slds-var-m-top_x-small slds-var-m-bottom_medium slds-m-horizontal_none ">
        <lightning-layout>
            <template if:true={fileList.length}>
                <c-file-comp-lwc-list-pane file-list={fileList}>

                </c-file-comp-lwc-list-pane>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout>
    </div>
    
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getFiles from '@salesforce/apex/fileCompLwcController.getFilesList';
export default class FileCompLwc extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId
    fileList = [];
    connectedCallback(){
        console.log('p con call bck');
    }

    renderedCallback(){
        console.log('p ren call bck');
    }

    @wire(getFiles, { recordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredFilesList({ error, data }) {

        console.log('wire');
        if (data) {
            console.log('before ', JSON.stringify(this.fileList) );
            this.fileList = []; 
            console.log('after ', JSON.stringify(this.fileList));
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                const conDoc = data[i].ContentDocument;
                const conVers = data[i].ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion;

                let f_Size = this.formatFileSize(conDoc.ContentSize);
                let f_Date = this.formatFileDate((conVers.CreatedDate).slice(0, 10));

                let fileItem = {
                    Id: data[i].Id, Title: conDoc.Title, Extension: conDoc.FileExtension,
                    ContentDocumentId: data[i].ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument: conDoc, CreatedDate: f_Date, fileSize: f_Size,
                    ThumbnailData: '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=' +
                        conDoc.LatestPublishedVersionId + '&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=' + data[i].ContentDocumentId,
                    DownloadUrl: `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/${data[i].ContentDocumentId}`
                };
                this.fileList.push(fileItem);
            }
        } else if (error) {

        }
    }

    //date displayed as May 16, 2021 which usually comes as YYYY-MM-DD format
    formatFileDate(dateStr) {
        const dt = new Date(dateStr);
        const year = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(dt);
        const month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(dt);
        const day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(dt);
        return month + ' ' + day + ', ' + year;
    }

    //file size displayed in MB or KB
    formatFileSize(fileSize) {
        let f = Math.abs(fileSize / 1024);
        return (f > 1024 ? Math.abs(fileSize / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2) + ' MB'
            : Math.round(f) + ' KB');
    }
}
```

Comment: if i remove this line " this.fileList = []; " in wire call ,  <template if:true={fileList.length}> is not working , why so

Comment: What do you mean by not working? `this.fileList = [];` re-initializes the variable to an empty list. Since it is set to `[]` in the class definition itself, this will do nothing on the first time your function is called. But, if the wire function is called multiple times it will delete the content from previous calls.

Comment: @HAlves 
not working i meant , `<template if:true={fileList.length}>` is rendering even when the list is empty and when this line `this.fileList = [];` is removed
just curious to know why exactly is this happening

Comment: That should not happen. Are you sure fileList is empty when it's rendering? Items are added to fileList even after your `console.log('after ', JSON.stringify(this.fileList));` call. To make sure you could also temporarily add a getter like `get test() { return JSON.stringify(this.fileList);}` and render that somewhere in the component like `{test}`. Maybe it has to do with the fact that you don't have `@track` in front of your fileList declaration. Without that lightning only tracks assignments to the variable itself, not changes to the content of objects or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign [] as default value to the property, in html, property.length will not throw exception. As soon as you don't default it, it will throw exception. You can understand from below image:-

Here i have tried accessing the length attribute when it is defaulted and when it is not
[image]

Comment: The default value is set in the class: `fileList = []`;